# What is the difference between std::input_or_output_iterator and std::indirectly_readable?

Tags: c++, iterator, c++20, c++-concepts

Reading about these concepts, in common words I see both of these concepts should allow to "dereference" an instance of the type. I can see they also have some other requirements, but they seem secondary. So why the need for 2 concepts, semantically speaking?

EDIT: My current understanding of them is as if `std::indirectly_readable` + `std::indirectly_writable` => close to `std::input_or_output_iterator`

Comment: "*I can see they also have some other requirements, but they seem secondary.*" Are you really saying that two things are the same if you consider all of the differences to be "secondary"?

Comment: Have you checked cppreference description? It clearly states the requirements and the relations: [input_or_output_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_or_output_iterator) + [indirectly_readable](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/indirectly_readable) ≈  [input_iterator](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/iterator/input_iterator)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`input_or_output_iterator` and `indirectly_readable` are two halves of `input_iterator`.

`indirectly_writable` and `input_or_output_iterator` are almost the two halves of `output_iterator` (there is also `*it++ = blah`).

`input_or_output_iterator` requires `++` to be somewhat sensible (both semantically and syntactically), and requires that whatever type `*it` is, taking a reference of it is legal (ie, it isn't `void`, as `void&` is not a legal type).

`indirectly_readable` and `indirectly_writable` place extra requirements on `*it` so you can (plausibly) read/write it.

`indirectly_writable` requires `*it = blah` to work.

`indirectly_readable` demands `std::iter_value_t`, `std::iter_reference_t`, `std::iter_rvalue_reference_t` all exist and that they have "sensible" relationships to each other and to `*it`.

The reference types of `std::input_iterator` need not be actual references.  But if they aren't actual references, you have to be careful about how `const&` and `&&` play with them, as these clauses are really modelled to work for references:

> ```
> std::common_reference_with<
>   std::iter_reference_t<In>&&, std::iter_value_t<In>&
> > &&
> std::common_reference_with<
>   std::iter_reference_t<In>&&, std::iter_rvalue_reference_t<In>&&
> > &&
> std::common_reference_with<
>   std::iter_rvalue_reference_t<In>&&, const std::iter_value_t<In>&
> >;
> ```

on references, those clauses basically require that your reference type be related to your value type, your rvalue reference type be related to your reference type, and your rvalue reference type be related to a `const&` reference to your value type.

Returning a *value* from `*it` does work (like `int`).

Doing this with "magic" reference types is going to be challenging.  I do not believe specializing https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/types/common_reference is legal.

Comment: So, short version is `indirectly_readable` requires returning an actual C++ reference type, while `input_or_output_iterator` allows returning an object type that *acts like* a reference.

Comment: @NicolBolas I don't think `referenceable` in `input_or_output_iterator` means "acts like a reference"; I think `int` qualifies as `referenceable`.

Comment: "`indirectly_readable` is a requirement that the `operator*` returns a reference" - Uh, there is no such requirement. You can have an iterator whose `*it` gives you an `int`.

Comment: @Barry Ah, I think I'm getting confused with LegacyInputIterator here -- "typename std::common_reference_t<std::iter_reference_t<I>&&,
                                     typename std::indirectly_readable_traits<I>::value_type&>;" -- which requires reference be a reference to value_type.

Comment: @Barry Fixed.  The restrictions seem strange to me now; it looks like they permit `int` but not a custom `IntReference` class.

Comment: @Yakk-AdamNevraumont LegacyForward required that the `reference` was a reference to the `value_type`, but LegacyInput didn't.

Comment: @Barry How does `value_type&` having a common reference with `iter_reference_t` become satisified without `iter_reference_t` being a reference?  Ah, I missed the `&&`.  That matches my memory as well.  Got it.